# Junit5 with spring-boot 1.5

Tags: junit5, spring-boot-test, junit-runner

I have a spring-boot application which uses **spring-boot** version `1.5.9.RELEASE`. To test this application I want to use **junit-jupiter** version `5.0.2`.

For simple service tests it works without any problems. But when it comes to testing rest endpoints, I am failing. The reason is the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation, which I used with junit4 to wire the everything together.

Is there a `SpringRunner` for junit5 before spring-boot 2?

---

**Update**

I just stumbled over an [article](http://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith) on how to run JUnit5 tests. Point 4 looks like a promising start.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To migrate from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5 you can replace `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

Unfortunately, **spring-boot** version `1.5.9-RELEASE` is based on Spring 4 and the `SpringExtension` is only available since Spring 5.

However, there is a solution since it's possible to use JUnit 5 and `SpringExtension` in Spring 4 by using `spring-test-junit5`. Just check the [instructions](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5) for setting up the dependencies.

Comment: If doing a full conversion to JUnit5, remove JUnit4 with:

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'    
    }

Comment: Could you please share the instructions instead of posting a link? Links may easily break, especially if you're linking a github readme