# Getting Exception while testing web layer in spring boot with Junit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit5

I am trying to write unit test cases for controller in spring boot with Junit 5 setup but while running simple test getting below exception message.

```
Test ignored.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils$MethodFilter.and(Lorg/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils$MethodFilter;)Lorg/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils$MethodFilter;

    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.<clinit>(SpringExtension.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:513)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:488)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.MutableExtensionRegistry.registerExtension(MutableExtensionRegistry.java:176)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.MutableExtensionRegistry.createRegistryFrom(MutableExtensionRegistry.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ExtensionUtils.populateNewExtensionRegistryFromExtendWithAnnotation(ExtensionUtils.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.prepare(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:143)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.prepare(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

I am trying to run below simple test case:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MainController.class)
class MainControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testfindAll() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/cronTime"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Below is **pom.xml** used:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
             <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.17.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.jimfs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jimfs</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To compile JSP files -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

Below is dependency tree, output of command (mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework.*):

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:jar:1.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.session:spring-session:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.8.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:1.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis:pom:1.0.1.RELEASE:compile
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the explicit version on `spring-test`? When using the Spring Boot parent POM, it'll manage all Spring-related versions for you (same for other dependencies). The error could come from a mismatch as you chose Spring Test 5.3.7, but Spring Boot < 2.0.

Comment: I tried to remove version from `spring-test` dependency or removed this dependecy, in both cases getting compile time error for `SpringExtension.class` not found with spring boot version `1.5.9.Release`. If I update spring boot version to `2.5.0` then does not get any compile time error and removed `spring-test` dependency.

Comment: @rieckpil, Can I get rid of compile time error for `SpringExtension.class` with spring boot version `1.5.9.Release`, is there any way to do this with old version of spring boot < 2.0?

Comment: Unfortunately not as the `SpringExtension` is part of Spring 5 which comes with Spring Boot > 2.0 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019430/junit5-with-spring-boot-1-5)

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue. Have you found a resolution? In my case my current theory is it's from a mismatch between the code using Spring 4, while attempting to use spring-test 5.